# Main.storyboard Failed to render and update auto layout status for MainViewController

Tags: swift, xcode12

> Main.storyboard: Failed to render and update auto layout status for MainViewController (BYZ-38-t0r): Failed to launch designables agent because tool was shutting down.

Had this error each time I compiled my project. I have one custom IBDesignable UIView (with Label and TextField) which I connected to MainViewController, all outlets from storyboard to MainVC are connected too.

Designable property of NavigationView in Identity Inspector shows an Error. What could be the reason of that?

**NavigationView.swift**

```
@IBDesignable
class NavigationView: UIView {
  
    @IBOutlet weak var locationLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    
    var textFieldText: ((_ text: String) -> Void)?
    var textWritten: String = ""
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        textField.delegate = self
        setupView()
    }
    
    @IBAction func tFeditingChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {
        print(sender.text!)
        locationLabel.text = sender.text
    }
  
    @IBInspectable
    var borderColor: UIColor = .black {
        didSet {
            layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable
    var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
        layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable
    var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        }
    }
}
```

Error snapshot:

[image]